# How to avoid triggering Firestore onSnapshot updates for hasPendingWrites = true?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to only trigger my `onSnapshot()` listener for updates where `docSnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites = false`.

On Firestore [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web_2), we get the following:

> **Events for local changes**
>
> Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately. This is because of an important feature called "latency compensation." When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend.
>
> Retrieved documents have a `metadata.hasPendingWrites` property that indicates whether the document has local changes that haven't been written to the backend yet. You can use this property to determine the source of events received by your snapshot listener:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
  var source = doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites ? "Local" : "Server";
  console.log(source, " data: ", doc.data());
});
```

Is it possible to avoid the update altogether or should I just check for the `hasPendingWrites` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the callback.  You will need to check `hasPendingWrites` in your code to determine if you want to do anything in the callback.

The reason why the callback always fires for local uncommitted write is because developers typically want to keep their UIs up to date ASAP with pending document changes, assuming that they are going to be written.  If that's not the case for you, you will need to use that property to determine what the user should see in your own UI based on the state of the document.

Comment: Its a shame the callback doesnt fire twice, once with `hasPendingWrites=true` and once with `false`, is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: @AndrewBullock I might be misunderstanding you. But hasPendingWrites can be called twice. According to the docs you need to set `includeMetadataChanges` to true in your snapshot creation.